How to fix this map to jump to usage/definition in a new tab?
I've had this map to be used with cscope/ctags for a while now:
nnoremap <C-}> <C-w><C-]><C-w>T
What it does is open the definition/usage in a new tab. This works great. Unless... there's multiple options. If there are, and I have to press a number to choose one of the locations, it only opens it in a split view.
How can I fix this?

The <C-]> key command selects the first tag to jump to (using the :tag logic). More information with: :help :stag
If you would like to chose which tags to jump to you could use the g<C-]> key command (using the :tjump logic). More information with: :help CTRL-W_g_CTRL-]
You could do:
nnoremap <C-}> <C-w>s<C-w>Tg<C-]>


This is interesting. My <C-]> does not select the first tag, but also gives me the selection dialog.
I tried your command. Unfortunately it appears to have the same effect as the one in the question: it also creates a split, not a tab.

In order to transform the slit into a tab I have added (like in your solution the <C-w>T part). I'm sure I get your question right. Do you want to have the choice or do you want the solution select automatically the first tag?

I always want it to open in a tab with this command. The current behavior I have for the jumping, I like to keep: it autojumps if there's only one option, it gives me a selection dialog when there's multiple possibilities. (I think this is default?)

I successfully reproduced the tab problem and provided a fix :-). Let me know if it works for you.

Yeeessh! This worked! Awesome! I've been using a stupid manual workaround for the past year now. This is going to save me a lot of time!
I will wait with accepting your answer for another 24 hours as per SE etiquette, but please already know that I'm very grateful! Dikke merci! ;)

Thanks for the feedback! I'm glad we could help you :-)

I think you could shorten to C-w g C-] C-w T

That was my first attempt but since g<C-]> could trigger the demand for a user input I switched to this new version that create the tab first and ends with g<C-]>.

c-w g c-] will (eventually) split the window, too

The problem I had with the solution is that <C-w>g<C-]> splits the window and ask for an input (if there is an ambiguity) to the user which make that the <C-w>T part is not executed. You have the split but not the desired tab as expected.
